# Scala Tree Match Case

Tags: scala, macros, tree

I'm fairly new to Scala and very new to writing macros and looking for a little help/advise.  I have the following code...

```
trait ValidationRule
case class Required() extends ValidationRule
case class HasLength(l: Int) extends ValidationRule
case class Person(name: String)

myMacro[Person] { p => p.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255)) }
```

Obviously there is some missing code here but this is just pseudo to get the question out.

So given a Tree representing `p => p.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255))` I'm trying to write a `match/case` to select out all expressions representing a `ValidationRule`. Something like:

```
case TypeApply(Select(_, ....
```

Can anyone suggest the best match case to be able to extract a List of Trees that represent each "all" `ValidationRules` from within the "is" method?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need a macro here? Can you explain where your `is` method comes from?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty certain I want a macro, the "is" method takes ValidationRules and the macro finds all occurrences to create an object containing the "name" of the property being tested plus the value and all the rules to run against it.

Not really looking to debate if my approach is the best way...more looking for help with the specific use case to do matching cases within a macro to find all ValidateRules in an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *definitely* look into [Quasiquotes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/intro.html).

Quasiquotes are used to do two things: to build Trees, and to pattern match Trees. They allow you to express the tree that you want to work with in terms of the equivalent Scala code. You let the quasiquote library deal with how Scala code maps to a Tree graph, and that's a good thing!

You can play around with them in the REPL, though the results might be slightly different in the macro universe:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> showRaw(cq"p => p.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255))")

res0: String = CaseDef(
  Bind(
    TermName("p"), 
    Ident(termNames.WILDCARD)), 
  EmptyTree, 
  Apply(
    Select(
      Select(
        Ident(TermName("p")), 
        TermName("name")), 
      TermName("is")), 
    List(
      Apply(
        Ident(TermName("Required")), 
        List()), 
      Apply(
        Ident(TermName("HasLength")), 
        List(Literal(Constant(255)))))))
```

The other thing you can do with Quasiquotes is to actually use them to pattern match.

```
scala> val fromTree = cq"p => p.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255))"
scala> val cq"p => p.name.is($x, $y)" = fromTree


x: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Required()
y: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = HasLength(255)
```

Now, you have to be careful, because that pattern ONLY matches if the user named their pattern variable `p`.

```
scala> val fromTree = cq"x => x.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255))"
scala> val cq"p => p.name.is($x, $y)" = fromTree

scala.MatchError: case (x @ _) => x.name.is(Required(), HasLength(255)) (of class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$CaseDef)
  ... 33 elided
```

Instead, you'll want to be a bit more generic:

```
scala> val cq"${p1:TermName} => ${p2:TermName}.name.is($x, $y)" = fromTree
p1: reflect.runtime.universe.TermName = x
p2: reflect.runtime.universe.TermName = x
x: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Required()
y: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = HasLength(255)

scala> p1 == p2
res2: Boolean = true
```

And, of course, if you were doing this as part of a pattern match, you could do:

```
case cq"${p1:TermName} => ${p2:TermName}.name.is($x, $y)" if p1 == p2 => 
  ???
```

Keep in mind that Macros are a deep, dark hole. If you're just getting started, expect to spend a lot of time getting your macro code correct. After that, expect to spend a lot of time dealing with edge cases.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, great response and that helps tons.  Quasiquotes looks like a nice way to learn/use and understand how to parse a Tree.

Comment: How would the "case cq" (last example) change if the "is" method took N number of ValidationRules?

So in other words the "is" method signature looks like this?

    def is(rules: ValidationRule*)

How can I use QUASIQUOTES in that case?

Comment: I think I quickly figured it out myself, it would look like this:

    case cq"${p1:TermName} => ${p2:TermName}.name.is(..$x)" if p1 == p2 => 

Which "x" would give you a list of ValidationRules.